# SQLite can't find column named 'x'

Tags: sqlite

I am working with `SQLite` database and I am facing a problem when comes to insert/remove column of a table.

Simply, I am trying to update the columns of a table called 'Category' in my database.

```
ALTER TABLE Category RENAME TO Category1;
CREATE TABLE Category (c_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, c_name TEXT, c_prefix TEXT, INT c_parent);
INSERT INTO Category (c_name, c_parent) SELECT name, parent FROM Category1;
```

but I am getting:

**Error: table Category has no column named c_parent**

I've also tried to DROP Category table and re-create it (as I know sometimes keeps reference to the old one) without any luck.

All, tables' and columns' names are correct (double-checked).

Any idea how I can make SQLite recognise the new table as the 'Category' one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CREATE statement has the type & name of the `c_parent` column reversed.

Answer (score 2):

You've transposed the type and column name in the last column of your create table, viz

```
CREATE TABLE Category 
...
c_parent INT )
```

Once you've confirmed all your data is safely across, you can `DROP TABLE Category1`